# Highcharts, type: 'mapbubble' causes an error 17

Tags: highcharts

When I am using the mapbubble I get an error 17
without it I see the map fine but of course no bubbles on the map :(

the data is

```
            series : [{
                    name: 'Countries',
                    mapData: mapData,
                    color: '#E0E0E0',
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                }, {
                    type: 'mapbubble',
                    name: 'Population 2013',
                    data: data,
                    maxSize: '12%',
                    mapData: mapData
                }]
```

and again, if I remove mapbubble I see the map, but with the type, I receieve error 17

tx for any assistance

regards

Sean

Answer (score 2):

[`'mapbubble'`](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#series<mapbubble>) is Highmaps series type. For Highcharts use [`'bubble'`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<bubble>). You will need to load [highcharts-more](https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js).

Demo: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bubble

Answer (score 1):

Error 17 means:

> The requested series type does not exist
>
> This error happens when you are setting chart.type or series.type to a
>   series type that isn't defined in Highcharts. A typical reason may be
>   that your are missing the extension file where the series type is
>   defined, for example in order to run an arearange series you need to
>   load the highcharts-more.js file.

Is it possible that you have [highcharts-more.js](https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js) missing?

Check this SO answer: [HighCharts and Map Bubble are not compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603884/highcharts-and-map-bubble-are-not-compatible)